# ¿Cómo cerrar WindowsForm y abrir Otro WindowsForm?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Que tal, quisiera saber como puedo pasar de Windows Form abierto a otro, por ejemplo cuando inicio mi aplicación se abre un windows Form donde tengo un botón, si hago click en el botón quiero cerrar el Windows Form activo y abrir otro. 
Lo hago por el momento de la siguiente manera pero no se si haya una mejor manera de hacerlo.

```
  Private Sub btnLayOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLayOut.Click
    Dim frmRuta As FrmRuta = New FrmRuta
    frmRuta.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola amigo, asi como esta esta bien :3 no te preocuepes

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias @Critical Ghost, solo una duda mas.
Lo que pasa que cuando cierro la ventana la aplicación sigue ejecutándose, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se cierre la aplicación por completo?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJ8ZdZA7xUA creo que con eso podras hacerlo y con Application.ExitThread() sales completamente de tu aplicacion
Suerte!

Comment: Se retiró la etiqueta visual-basic porque es ambigua y se ha sugerido su quemado. Véase https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65

Answer (score 3):

```
private void btnVer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewTableCWS frm = new ViewTableCWS();

        frm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Es un ejemplo mio, me abre el nuevo form y me cierra el actual

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1.ActiveForm.Hide()
Form2.Show()
```

Podrías intentar esto.